# Help text blocks show up randomly in node add/edit form with Drupal Bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, theming

I can't get rid of this display bug.

I set a `Help text` for all my content-type's fields to guide my users in the node add/edit forms.

However, these text blocks seem to show up **randomly** in the form page. Illustration:

[image]

Yes, I can assure you that all the fields have a help text set up in the administration interface.

There are no similarities between the field's types. There are text, select lists, taxonomy term reference, etc...

I tried without the field groups (we never know). But no luck.

My config is Drupal 7.32 and my theme is based on Bootstrap 7.x-3.0.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

No, they not appear in HTML source at all.

Here is a part of the source code showing one field without help text and one field with help text:

```
<div id="edit-field-function-title" class="field-type-text field-name-field-function-title field-widget-text-textfield form-group col-xs-6 form-wrapper form-group">
  <div id="field-function-title-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-type-textfield form-item-field-function-title-und-0-value form-item form-group">
      <label for="edit-field-function-title-und-0-value">
      <input id="edit-field-function-title-und-0-value" class="text-full form-control form-text required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="60" value="" name="field_function_title[und][0][value]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="edit-field-organisme" class="field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-name-field-organisme field-widget-autocomplete-deluxe-taxonomy form-group col-xs-6 form-wrapper form-group">
  <div class="form-type-autocomplete-deluxe form-item-field-organisme-und form-item form-group">
    <label for="edit-field-organisme-und">
    <div class="autocomplete-deluxe-container">
      <input id="autocomplete-deluxe-input--2" class="autocomplete-deluxe-form form-control form-text jquery-once-2-processed ui-autocomplete-input autocomplete-deluxe-form-single" type="text" size="60" value="" name="field_organisme[und][textfield]" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
      <div class="autocomplete-deluxe-throbber autocomplete-deluxe-closed"> </div>
      <p class="help-block">Ce champ est destiné à l'organisme, structure, société, entreprise, cause, fédération, etc. à laquelle la personne physique ou l'entité appartient et pour laquelle elle est référencée dans Grape.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you view source is the markup for the help text there (and being hidden via css possibly), or is it missing from the markup altogether?

Comment: They not appear in the markup at all. Sorry to forget to mention that of course!!! @Clive

Comment: I don't know the Bootstrap theme too well but the responsible party is probably `bootstrap_form_element()` in theme/system/form-element.func.php, round about line 70

Comment: Indeed, if I comment some lines in this function, all my help texts appear. That's embarrassing because I don't see yet how I am going to fix that... Well, thank you very much for pointing me the source of this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple actually. It was a config in theme administration that set all text blocks having less than 200 chars as tooltips and not as help blocks. All I had to do is disabling that config:

[image]